# Pass array of models from view to controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2

Is it possible to pass array of models from view to controller? How?

Suppose my model is

```
public class Car
{
    public string Name
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
    public int Price
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
}
```

And I have a <form> where user can dynamically add new cars. When he submits, I want to catch it in the action method

```
public ActionResult CreateCars(Car[] cars)
```

Is it possible?

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3230463/net-mvc-pass-back-complex-object-or-list-array-from-view-to-controller

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think so.

I believe you'd have to build the form as you went and catch the formcollection.

```
public ActionResult CreateCars(FormCollection formCollection)
```

And then go through all the elements of the formCollection.